# How to send values set to pojo references to another activity and displayed in adapter view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-adapterview

I have parsed the json response using the pojo classes and I want these values to be carried to another activity and there I want to show them in adapter view.

FeedPojo.java

```
public class FeedPojo {
private static String id;
    private static String partnerId;
    private static String type;
    private static String name;
    private static String description;
    private static String start;
    private static String text;
    private static String photoUrl;
    private static String videoUrl;
    public FeedPojo(String id,String type,String name,String description,String start){

            this.setId(id);
            this.setType(type);
            this.setName(name);
            this.setDescription(description);
            this.setStart(start);
    }
public FeedPojo(String id,String text,String photoUrl,String videoUrl,String isNew){

        this.setId(id);
        this.setText(text);
        this.setPhotoUrl(photoUrl);
        this.setVideoUrl(videoUrl);
        this.setIsNew(isNew);

    }
}
```

MainActiviy.java

```
    FeedPojo feedPojoNews = new FeedPojo(
promoJsonObject.getString("id"),                                                                                                              promoJsonObject.getString("text"),                                                                promoJsonObject.getString("photoUrl"),                                                                promoJsonObject.getString("videoUrl"),                                                                promoJsonObject.getString("isNew"));
    Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoNewsId" + feedPojoNews.getId());                                                Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoNewsText" + feedPojoNews.getText());                                                Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoNewsPhotoUrl" + feedPojoNews.getPhotoUrl());                                                Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoNewsVideoUrl" + feedPojoNews.getVideoUrl());                                                Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoNewsisNew" + feedPojoNews.getIsNew());           FeedPojo feedPojoPartnerGn = new FeedPojo(promoJsonObject.getString("id"),                                                                                                                                    
    promoJsonObject.getString("text"),                                                                        promoJsonObject.getString("photoUrl"),                                                                    promoJsonObject.getString("videoUrl"),                                                                                                                                                                                       Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoPartnerId" + feedPojoPartnerGn.getId());
    Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoPartnerImageurl" + feedPojoPartnerGn.getPhotoUrl());
    Log.d(TAG, "FeedPojoPartnerbuyUrl" + feedPojoPartnerGn.getVideoUrl());
```

Comment: You can pass the Object through Intent or Bundle if it is not serialize. First serialize you pojo class then send it to another activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

implement Serializable

```
public class FeedPojo implements Serializable {
private static String id;
    private static String partnerId;
    private static String type;
    private static String name;
    private static String description;
    private static String start;
    private static String text;
    private static String photoUrl;
    private static String videoUrl;
    public FeedPojo(String id,String type,String name,String description,String start){

            this.setId(id);
            this.setType(type);
            this.setName(name);
            this.setDescription(description);
            this.setStart(start);
    }
public FeedPojo(String id,String text,String photoUrl,String videoUrl,String isNew){

        this.setId(id);
        this.setText(text);
        this.setPhotoUrl(photoUrl);
        this.setVideoUrl(videoUrl);
        this.setIsNew(isNew);

    }
}
```

then put data in bundle like this

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putSerializable("DATA", feedPojoNews);
  Intent intent = new 
  Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  startActivity(intent);
```

In second Activity Extract data like this

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 FeedPojo feedPojo= (FeedPojo ) bundle.getSerializable("DATA");
```